# Selenium XPath for WebTable using parent & sibling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to automate the web table on the demoqa site https://demoqa.com/webtables where I am aiming to click the edit and delete button for a specific user. Please find the attached screenshot for reference.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcx5o.jpg)

I am trying to click the edit and delete button for the user 'Cierra' hence I have created the customize XPath '//div[contains(text(),'cierra@example.com')]//following::div[text()='Insurance']//following::div//div//span[@title='Edit']'

Trying to click the edit and delete button using the contains text with email 'cierra@example.com' however I see four results even I use the unique username. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
(//div[contains(text(),'cierra@example.com')]//following::div[text()='Insurance']//following::div//div//span[@title='Edit'])[1]
```

you can enclose the result in bracket and call [1] , to get first one:

But you don't have to over complicate it , just get email then go back to parent and get span under that parent ,:

```
//div[contains(text(),'cierra@example.com')]/..//span[@title="Edit"]
```

if you still want to use fancy xpath locator then use :

```
//div[contains(text(),'cierra@example.com')]/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'Insurance')]/following-sibling::div//span[@title='Edit']
```